# Changes made to NSGraphicsContext.current

Tags: swift, cocoa, nsview, drawrect

I am making changes to the current NSGraphicContext, from inside the drawRect() method of a NSView, and everything works OK. Any changes made, are persistent through the subsequent calls to drawRect() method.

However, what i want to do, is to make changes to the current context, from within another object's method. This method is indeed called, from inside DrawRect() method. But these changes, are not persistent.

Code is like this:

```
class SomeView:NSView {

  override func drawRect(dirtyRect: NSRect) {
    // myAObject is an instance of a Class i create, and stored inside SomeView
    // myAObject's exexcuteCode() method, makes changes to the current NSGraphicsContext
    myAObjectIntance.executeCode() 

    // In subsequent calls of drawRect, as the user keeps drawing using the 
    // mouse, another object, say myBObject's executeCode() method, draws,
    // lets say a rectangle.
    myBObjectIntance.executeCode()

    // Problem is, that any changes done to the current context by myAObjectIntance.executeCode()
    // seem to be lost.

    // If i change the context and draw inside the same method call, everything is OK.
    // If changes and drawing are done by different objects, changes are lost.
  }
}
```

From inside both methods, myAObjectIntance.executeCode() and myBObjectIntance.executeCode(), i get  the current NSGraphicsContext using code like this:

```
NSGraphicsContext.current!.compositeOperation = .copy
```

or

```
NSGraphicsContext.current!.compositeOperation = .clear
```

I added a small project that changes foreground color. Change in color is not preserved, between sequential calls of drawRect().
[NSGraphicsContextTest.zip](https://costaschatzinikolas.gr/NSGraphicsContextTest.zip)

Comment: Please post a [mre].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you're expecting your drawing and changes to be preserved between multiple calls to drawRect; that's not going to happen. Each time drawRect is called, the state of the context is reset. That's by design. So each time drawRect is called, you need to set the state of the context to be whatever you need it to be, and draw to fill the area specified by the dirtyRect parameter.

Comment: Well, i was (incorrectly) assuming that any changes were preserved. The program i am trying to develop, draws all the time, using the mouse input, and i was thinking that setting so many times the state of the context, might put extra delay. But it seems there is no other way. Thank you so much!!!!

Comment: The cost of doing the drawing faaaaaaaaaaar outweighs simply setting a property. (You should also mark the answer as correct.)